# A new sabermetric baseball statistic?

Tags: baseball, statistics, sabermetrics

Let's award a batter 
2 points for a single, 
3 pts for a double, 
4 pts for a triple, and 
5 pts for a homerun.

To complete the statistic, let's award the batter 
1 point for a walk, and 
1 point if he is hit by the pitch.

Call it **"Advanced Batting Index"**.

If we calculate a batter's average Advanced Batting Index, is this equivalent to OPS?

Comment: I'm wondering if this is an accurate simplification of OPS or did I miss something in my calculation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite. The denominators are different for SLG and OBP, which makes combining the numerators more complicated than you're making it:

```
SLG = TB / AB

OBP = (H + BB + HBP) / (AB + BB + SF + HBP)
```

Take a look at the [equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-base_plus_slugging#Equation).

Answer (score 1):

OPS is on-base percentage + slugging/ at bats.

Slugging gives 1 for single, 2 for double, three for triple, four for HR.
On base percentage give 1 for all those, 1 for walk and 1 for HBP.

So yours is OPS*At Bats.

Comment: So if we calculate a batter's average Advanced Batting Index (average meaning we divide by AT BATS), would you agree it is OPS?